# Setting Up A Guest User Account In OS X?

Tags: macos, guest-account

I have been advised that if you let people use your Mac, is it better for them to use **A Guest User Account** as when they have finished, all settings etc will be deleted and your Mac will be left "untouched", rather than running the risk of them changing settings etc and potentially "screwing things up" if you let them use your account - which could be a disaster.

Guidance on how to achieve/enable this, as well as disabling/deleting as necessary would be much appreciated ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Setting up a guest account on Mountain Lion](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11321):

> 1. Choose Apple menu > System Preferences, and then click Users & Groups.
> 2. Click the lock icon to unlock it, and then type an administrator name and password.
> 3. Select Guest User in the list of accounts.
> 4. To let a guest user log in to the computer, select “Allow guests to log in to this computer.”
>
>    However, guest users can’t log in remotely.
> 5. If you let guests log in, you can also set up parental controls for guests by selecting “Enable parental controls” and clicking Open Parental Controls.
>
>    For more information about the limits you can set, see this help topic:
>
>    [Set up parental controls](http://support.apple.com/kb/index?page=link&apdid=mh35829&viewlocale=en_US&bookId=133741)
> 6. To let guests use your shared folders and their contents from another computer on your network, select “Allow guests to connect to shared folders.”

Answer (score -1):

Just follow this guidelines from Apple: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH4600?viewlocale=en_US

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.